# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < google-analytics

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics

I followed the google analytics explanation to add this right after the body

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-15481145-1', 'mydomain.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

However in Google Chrome in Dev Tools I get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < www.google-analytics.com/:1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you getting this error every time? Did you check the network inspector to see the requests being made?

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm getting this kind of error.. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Convert the code to UTF-8 Format. I was getting the same error. It resolved when complete page code is converted to UTF-8

Comment: how to do this?